# Regex to capture JPG images only

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex in PHP:

```
$regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
```

It captures all image tag sources in a string, but I want to only capture JPG files. I've tried to mess around with (.*) but I've only proven that I suck at regex... Right now I'm filtering the array but feels too much like a hack when I can just do it straight up with a proper match.

Comment: What kind of images tags? What are you filtering?

Comment: In general, it's not possible to tell the content type of a resource based on its url.

Comment: I'm pulling web pages via cURL and then searching for <img> tags to get it's source file.

Comment: the period * characters are just saying search for any character 0 or more times until you match a quote.  Has nothing to do with the file extension as it may appear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$regex = '/<img ([^>]* )?src=[\"\']([^\"\']*\.jpe?g)[\"\']/Ui';
```

I also removed the extra `|` in the character classes that was not needed.

Comment: This breaks, e.g. on `<img alt="1 >> epsilon" src="graph.jpeg">` or `<pre> <IMgetJPEG classrc="rc.jpeg"> ...`.

Comment: @Svante: I've fixed the regexp so it also matches "jpeg", and does not match the tag "imgetjpeg" or attribute "classrc" (by adding spaces as appropriate).

Comment: `<img alt="my image"src="a.jpeg">`.

Comment: And this doesn't even touch on the whole "not a regular language" problem, HTML comments, `<pre>` regions, strings in embedded scripts, etc..  Leave the parsing of HTML to HTML parsers, that's what their job is, and there are enough of them.

Comment: @Svante: you're preaching to the choir with "don't use regexes to parse html". :p :)

Answer (score 4):

First, get all `img` tags with an HTML parser.  Then, take those whose `src` attribute's value is matched by the regex `\.(jpeg|jpg)$`.

For example, using [this parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.foo.org/bar.html');
foreach ($html->find('img') as $img) {
    if (preg_match ("\.(jpeg|jpg)$", $img->src) {
        //save $img or $img->src or whatever you need
    }
}
```

*Edit:* I shortened the regular expression.  You can also use `\.jpe?g$`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. A quick look does show that it uses fopen though -- which I've disabled and have tested to be less reliable than cURL for my use.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to search for the .jpg before the closing quotes I believe

```
$regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*\.jpg)[\"|\']/Ui';
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, print_r shows that the array has the whole tag -- "<img src="blahblah"> -- as values.

Comment: Sorry, I was just appended the .jpg to your code without testing it.  I made some edits, although there seem to be some better options already ;).

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful to escape `'` since you are using it as PHP delimeter.

Also searching the file which end by `.jpg` or `jpeg` would make it.

```
$regex = '/<img[^>]*src=["\']([^\'"]*)\.(jpg|jpeg)["\'][^>]*>/Ui';
```

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. It's my first time here and I forgot to quote it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*[.]jpg)[\"|\']/Ui';
```

Answer (score 0):

You all forgot that tags may have spaces between < and img

So a correct regexp should start with
`/<\s*img`

Comment: Yes, and this is only one small detail that HTML parsers have already solved.

Comment: Indeed. Using a stable HTML parser is a better approach (even if in some circumstances it may not be an option)